# How to open this hotel piano?

Tags: piano

I am in a hotel in Turkey.

When I visit hotels I usually don't ask beforehand if I am allowed to play the piano because most of the time they say no. I found out that it's just better to sit and play and they stop you, or they don't and they have fun.

I encountered this piano and its lid is kind of locked, won't lift up. If this is some basic lid that I need to pull something, I'll try it (if it doesnt require a key). If not I will ask them if they can open.

On the bottom-left side of the piano (see picture) there's some switch like in old-school clocks (to adjust the clocks).

Do you have any idea if this can be opened easily?
Im hoping there is some trick to it, to prevent bashing the piano by children etc.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe this is not a piano, but a really big [music box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_box).  The knob on the underside is the key to wind the [mainspring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainspring).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a business that locks its piano does so because they don't want it played without permission. We can't help you open it any more than we could help break into a guest room or open any other part of their private property.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I do not think this is the correct platform for getting tips on how to gain access to others peoples instruments without their consent.

Comment: It's about playing music, albeit in a devil-may-care way. I've often played pianos on holiday without permission, and only been asked to stop once, as it was 12 o'clock at night, and people were singing along to it. Often, it's easier just to say 'no', and keep it locked, but words with the right person would help. Every piano has a lock, some with a key, some with an Allen key. but I consider it a valid question for someone who, maybe, has inherited a piano (nice) and can't open it.

Comment: I have a couple of friends who will do this wherever they go, right around the world. No-one ever tells them to stop; probably no-one ever realised they're getting a 5 grand a night entertainer for free… but they know what's good when they hear it. Go for it.

Comment: Ever considered the possibility that the piano *used* to be unlocked at some point but now isn't? (I'm fairly certain a piano in an ice cream shop we used to frequent was locked in one of my visits.)

Comment: Maybe it's a cosmetic piano - there to add a touch of class to the decor, but not actually playable.

Comment: Maybe if this could be linked to harmonic analysis and Neo-Riemannian theory?

Comment: Voting to reopen.  If the management doesn't want it played, why put it in the lobby?  If it's decoration or a player piano, the would-be player would figure that out pretty quickly, no?  At any rate, I don't think we should be closing questions on morality grounds, especially when no one's health or safety would be threatened.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - or - 'I want to play the piano, but can't find the right key'?

Comment: Yes, questions about finding a particular key are off-topic.

Comment: Anyone read the title and thought - well, yes?